# Printer Communication Capture

Tags: c#, printing, driver, capture

If I need to post this elsewhere let me know.

We have some old software thats being re-written, that uses a printerdriver to a propriatery printer.

I need to rewrite the software bypassing the print driver and go directly to the printer. I do have the specs for the printer communication, thats fine, but what Id like to do is monitor the communications to the printer to view its contents (from the existing software that Im re-writing) and compare it to the specs, and what I will be sending it for validation.

I have to make sure Im not missing anything.

Any ideas on how I might be able to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to re-write the driver or are you talking about opening the serial/parallel port directly and writing your own user-mode "driver"?

Comment: I will be opening the serial/parrlell/USB/Ethernet directly depending on configuration. So I will be re-writing the whole thing. I dont think opening the ports should be a problem and putting together the data to send over the port, (I did allot of that with old modems over serial). But I want to capture what the current driver sends to the printer so I can duplicate that, and validate my code, with the printer manufacturer specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture the traffic you have to basic options.

**1. Use software**

If you are using ethernet, you can use a program like [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) or [USBTrace](http://download.cnet.com/USBTrace/3000-2086_4-10401250.html) to capture the packets that are being sent out.  There are similar programs for USB.

**2. Use hardware**

Another option would be to use an external  logic analyzer.  It's basically a box that sits in-between the computer and the printer that captures all the data, then uses software to decode it.  There are some inexpensive options available (USBEE, [Bus Pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate), and [Total Phase Beagle](http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle_usb12/).

I own a USBEE and I've used it to debug a simple USB device.  It works well enough for that.  The software is a little clunky though.